# Bootstrap: is there an options to show the accordion only by mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, accordion

Is there an option in bootstrap that i can use an accordion 
for my mobile page. For de default page i have lot of space to show the content.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Bootstrap has these "Responsive utility classes" built in:

```
.visible-phone
.visible-tablet
.visible-desktop
.hidden-phone
.hidden-tablet
.hidden-desktop
```

You can add any of these classes to an element, such as the accordion, to control what devices it is displayed/hidden on.

To only show the accordion on mobile devices, you would add `hidden-desktop` to the accordion classes, something like this:

`<div class="panel-group hidden-desktop" id="accordion">`

**This is all you need to do.** You can stop here.

However, for the sake of completeness, I'll mention that there are other responsive utility classes in Bootstrap that allow more control.

```
.visible-xs
.visible-sm
.visible-md
.visible-lg
.hidden-xs
.hidden-sm
.hidden-md
.hidden-lg
```

The last eight classes are based explicitly on device resolution:

```
.*-xs (<768px)
.*-sm (≥768px)
.*-md (≥992px)
.*-lg (≥1200px)
```

Comment: Just to point out incase anyone sees this now I believe that the visible-phone/tablet/desktop are no longer supported and best practise is to use xs, sm, md, lg.

Comment: does it mean that you need to write your HTML twice? One for accordion and one without?